# Why does UITableView crash when I insert and delete at the same time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have the following code:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *rows; // pre-filled with 2 rows

// ...

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.rows.count;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSIndexPath *newRowIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+1 inSection:indexPath.section];
    MyRowRepresentation *newRowRepresentation = [MyRowRepresentation new];
    [self.rows insertObject:newRowRepresentation atIndex:newIndexPath.row];

    NSMutableIndexSet *indicesToRemove = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
    NSMutableArray<NSIndexPath*> *indexPathsToRemove = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (int i = 0; i < self.row.count; i++)
    {
        MyRowRepresentation *mrr = self.rows[i];
        if (mrr != newRowRepresentation && [self meetsDeletionRequirements:mrr])
        {
            [indicesToRemove addIndex:i];
            [indexPathsToRemove addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:indexPath.section]];
        }
    }

    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newRowIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [self.rows removeObjectsAtIndexes:indicesToRemove];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToRemove withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [tableView endUpdates]; // crash here
}
```

And when I select a row, I get this:

```
2015-12-14 20:27:17.761 Now[1685:1753114] ERROR CRASH #(null) attempt to insert row 3 into section 1, but there are only 3 rows in section 1 after the update
2015-12-14 20:27:17.828 Now[1685:1753114] ERROR Stack Trace: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185684248 <redacted> + 160
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001970a80e4 objc_exception_throw + 60
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001856840ec <redacted> + 0
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000186538ed4 <redacted> + 112
    4   UIKit                               0x000000018a2e57ec <redacted> + 5256
    5   Now                                 0x0000000100092914 -[MyTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 1234
    ...
)
2015-12-14 20:44:48.933 Now[1692:1754780] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 3 into section 1, but there are only 3 rows in section 1 after the update'
```

But I'm perplexed; the following steps should work, no?

1. I insert the new row representation into my tracking array.
2. I start updates on the table, which should put it in a "pause" state.
3. I remove the row representations I don't want from my tracking array, which doesn't include the new one.
4. I remove the table view rows which correspond to the removed row representations.
5. I insert the table view row which corresponds to the new row representation.

To crash the app, I select one of the original 2 rows, then the other.

**What don't I understand which causes this to crash?**

Comment: Move the `beginUpdates` to the top,of the method

Comment: The call to `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` must be before the call to `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`.

Comment: @Paulw11 There's no need to move `beginUpdates`. It just needs to be before the call to the various table modification methods.

Comment: @rmaddy is it actually more subtle than that?  Is it the fact that the index paths for which ever operation occurs second (be that insert or delete) will be affected by the operation that occurs first, so if the delete is called first then the insertion point may be invalid and vice-versa?

Comment: @Paulw11 Correct. This is all covered in the "Table View Programming Guide for iOS".

Comment: right, so then simply changing the order of the delete/insert may still result in problems; the OP actually needs to be smarter about determining the index paths for the operations. Performing the insert first and then incrementing the indexPath.row for deletions after the insertion point would seem to be the most straightforward

Comment: @Paulw11 - I think rmaddy has it right.  A working order is change the datasource first, completely, then the table view.  Order the table view updates to match the datasource changes exactly, using the very same index paths that worked on the datasource.  The only thing wrong with the OP code as far as I can tell, is that it doesn't finish the datasource changes before updating the table

Comment: Increment  self.rows.count before insertion.

Comment: Good morning! I moved the beginUpdates to the top of the method, both inserts to before the loop, and both deletes to after it. The crash persisted. If I'm missing something and you know how to solve this, please leave an answer with your solution.

Comment: Little late to the party, but maddy said to insert after delete, you tried it the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't answer *why*, but I did solve this problem by using a single reload call instead of multiple insert/delete calls:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *rows; // pre-filled with 2 rows

// ...

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.rows.count;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    NSIndexPath *newRowIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+1 inSection:indexPath.section];
    MyRowRepresentation *newRowRepresentation = [MyRowRepresentation new];
    [self.rows insertObject:newRowRepresentation atIndex:newIndexPath.row];

    NSMutableIndexSet *indicesToRemove = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
    NSMutableArray<NSIndexPath*> *indexPathsToRemove = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (int i = 0; i < self.row.count; i++)
    {
        MyRowRepresentation *mrr = self.rows[i];
        if (mrr != newRowRepresentation && [self meetsDeletionRequirements:mrr])
        {
            [indicesToRemove addIndex:i];
            [indexPathsToRemove addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:indexPath.section]];
        }
    }

    [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```